# Pointer assigned function address shows a different value than function address

Tags: c++

I have a function, say

```
void myfunc()
```

and if I declare a pointer and assign it the function's address as follows

```
void *test_pointer = (void*) &myfunc;
```

and go in debug mode with Visual Studio, I will get the following from the watch window

```
Name                       Value
&myfunc                    0x000000013fc06570
test_pointer               0x000000013fa4786f
```

Now I would expect these two values to be identical, why is it not the case?

Comment: Try with : `void (*test_pointer)() = &myfunc;`

Comment: `void*` should be used very rarely in C++, typically when interacting with a C interface, as there is almost always a better alternative. Not enough context here to provide a better option than the one provided by @BoHalim

Comment: If you're building with edit and continue enabled the compiler will generate a jump table that can be updated to point to a new function when it's created. The pointer value you are seeing is probably different because the `void` variable is pointing to the entry in the jump table while you're also looking at the address of the actual function in the dbugger.

Comment: Also try showing real code, instead of fantasy code. This can be the expected result for virtual class methods, and since the shown code is obviously not real code, but fantasy code, no authoritative conclusion can be made because of that.

Comment: Also, don't use parenthetical casts in C++. There are four cast types: `static_cast`, `const_cast`, `dynamic_cast`, and `reinterpret_cast`. Pick the one you mean and use it. The parenthetical cast can perform *any* of these cast types, and *which cast it performs can change* if the types involved in the operation change.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Strictly speaking, the C++ standard doesn't require an implementation to support conversion of function pointers to an opaque object pointer (`void*`). You've probably been told `void*` can point to anything, but that "anything" isn't necessarily functions.

Since this feature is only conditionally supported, there's no telling how such a conversion will take place. It could be that your implementation will only convert to and from `void*` whilst preserving the value (that's the minimum requirement the standard places). But the value need not be the same in both pointer representations.

To quote the latest C++ standard draft on this, [[expr.reinterpret.cast]/8](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.reinterpret.cast#8):

> Converting a function pointer to an object pointer type or vice versa
>   is conditionally-supported. The meaning of such a conversion is
>   implementation-defined, except that if an implementation supports
>   conversions in both directions, converting a prvalue of one type to
>   the other type and back, possibly with different cv-qualification,
>   shall yield the original pointer value.